# Questions lists: Votes, not score?

Tags: discussion, user-interface

I'm no expert in any language, especially English, however..

In all questions lists, there're columns for *votes*, *answers* and *views*. The *answers* and *views* make sense, but a positive number in *votes* shows the sum of positive and negative votes for a question, not the number of *votes* that one might expect. At least this is what I am assuming since *votes* can be negative.

How about renaming *votes* to *score* or something else that's less misleading?

Comment: Yeah, that question did not show up in any searches (at this site – did not try external engines).